# Override initWithFrame in subview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to create a custom view inherited from another custom view

when I override the `initWithFrame` method in the sub view it returns an object of the super view

Here is my code for sub view

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self) {
    UIView *view =
        [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"myView"
                                     owner:self
                                     options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

    [self attachContentView:view];
  }

return self;

}


- (void)attachContentView:(UIView *)contentView {
    CGRect frame = contentView.frame;

    frame.size.height -= self.headerView.frame.size.height;


  [contentView setFrame:frame];
  [self.contentView addSubview:contentView];
  [self layoutSubviews];

}
```

Comment: What do you mean it returns the superview?

Comment: it returns an instance of the super view,which leads to unrecognizing the subclass selectors

Comment: Please show how you are allocating your object; if you are getting an instance of the superclass then your are allocating an instance of the superclass, not the subclass

Comment: or do you mean `view` is the superclass?  If so, what custom class have you specified for the root object in your nib file?

Comment: The super class nib has the super class as a custom class.

Comment: So, the root object of the nib file `myView.nib` is SuperClass and you are wondering why `view` is an instance of `SuperClass`?

Comment: yes I want to load super nib and add another view on its children

Comment: Can you post your attachContentView method?

Comment: @jakedunc I added it.

Comment: And what is the problem here? after calling initWithFrame the class isn't what you expect?

Comment: it returns an instance of the super class not the sub class